# ZVS induction heater MOSFET failure?

Tags: mosfet, design, oscillator, failure, zvs

I'm an electrical engineering student and I've been super excited to put a zvs induction heater together.

I finally got all my parts, turned it on, and smoked a MOSFET almost instantly.  Happened twice actually.  It's just one that gets hot the other seems to do nothing.  My work coil is about 2+2.  I originally tested it to be about .2mH but I took a turn out.  My choke started at something like 70mH and I took 2 turns off of that.  The caps are .1uF 1000V and the MOSFETs are irf540s.  I've tried troubleshooting on a number of sites but can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions going forward?
[image: circuit][image: paint drawing][image: can take a closer one if needed]

Comment: The hand drawn schematic you posted shows that you shorted the 460's to the 10K's to LM781. Hopefully that's just a poor drawing?

Comment: ya i did mess up the drawing the center line is supposed to be the ground and the 460s come from the lm781

Comment: My gut tells me your circuit is not oscillating reliably. I don't think you should feel much magnetic field in your work piece at working frequencies. If only one MOSFET is getting hot then it may not be starting. If you PC-PSU fan is turning on it means that a lot of current is being drawn not conclusive if you have oscillation though. Make sure all your high current wires are short and thick and your feedback connections are reasonably symmetrical.

Answer (score 3):

I think I see your problem... You state that you had a 70 mH choke originally but then removed two turns to get down to the picture showing 40mH choke. I don't really think from your pictures and from your description of two turns changing the inductance that you have an inductance that large. If it's that enormous coil with electrical tape around it acting as your choke, then you have something in the uH area of inductance I would expect. **How are you measuring your inductance?** With an inductance multiple orders of magnitude too small and very likely a resistance equally small since there's hardly any turns on your choke, you end up with huge amounts of inrush current with no resistance or inductance to slow down your current. Right away you'll heat the mosfets up and blow them out.

Comment: The choke I didn't actually measure that's just what it said when I ordered it.  It was from Ebay so it could be wrong.  The work coil I measured with a real expensive RLC meter at school.  I suppose I could try to actually measure it though I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: So i calculated it you were right I was at about 4uf not mf.  So I have some magnet wire and 2 of those cores I could stack them and use a ton of windings.  According to the Al value I'd need about 140 turns to get 2mH.  I was thinking about trying it with .5mH from 70 turns.  Otherwise I guess I can just order a new core and wait would prefer not to blow any more transistors haha

Comment: Glad my shot in the dark yielded some useful results. If you have an inductance meter to check your inductance, and the time to do it, I would just hand wrap them. Otherwise, going the shopping route is easier to hit your specs.

Comment: Ya I wrapped as many times as I could around the 3 toroids I had and it finally worked.  Still needed to be bigger so I ordered some cores with higher permeability.  Plus I fried my last mosfet so I have to wait for more of those haha.

Comment: I had it goin for a while.  Decided to rebuild it and got a toroid with a higher aL value.  I made a new coil and zvs circuit but now I'm getting a lot of heat in my choke.  It'll run If I hook the three cores I have together but the cores will get very hot and I see little inductive heating occur.  Any Idea what might cause the choke to be getting so hot?

Comment: It's most likely caused by the resistance of the cores. If the wires are thin and they're wrapped a lot to get a high inductance, you'll often end up with a rather high resistance. Check it with an ohm meter to see what the resistance is. Once you know the resistance, we can figure out the current since you appear to have 12 V across it. From that we can figure out the power wasted through the inductor.

Comment: Well I decided to wrap a new choke with thicker wire and was still havin some problmes.  The thinner choke was about 3mH the larger 1. something.  Both were measuring under 20mOhms.  With the thicker choke the toroid wasnt getting as hot but my mosfets were getting very hot and I could feel some heat on the ground wires.  Also im using a pc psu and with this setup the fan wont come on when the coil is connected.  If I take the power wire off it will run fine. I did notice when i was using a tighter rapped work coil there was a significant magnetic field on object in work coil so did something

Comment: Well without much load in your circuit, the mosfets will have to absorb much of it. If you're feeling heat in the ground lines, I'd recommend thicker/more wires. Have you checked the amount of average current you're consuming? Make sure you're well within specs for the mosfets otherwise their life will end early.

Comment: Well a few notes. For one only 1/2 of the work coil is getting hot.  I beefed all the wires and ground seems a little warm back at the supply. I'm wondering if there mmight be somethin happening with choke. Its only if I use my old and new chokes together will the fan turn on even though their inductance is much smaller even though circuit still not performing correctly.  Heres datasheethttp://www.mag-inc.com/File%20Library/Product%20Datasheets/Ferrite/New%20Ferrite%20data%20sheets/ZJ42915TC.pdf  gotta say I'm lost

Comment: My gut tells me your circuit is not oscillating reliably.  I don't think you should feel much magnetic field in your work piece at working frequencies. If only one MOSFET is getting hot then it may not be starting.  If you PC-PSU fan is turning on it means that a lot of current is being drawn not conclusive if you have oscillation though.  Make sure all your high current wires are short and thick and your feedback connections are pretty symmetrical.

Comment: @KalleMP This is 3 years old. You also put this on my answer so the asker will never see your comment. Mb move it to the question if you think that'll help future people?